# Extrair lista de objeto de JSON

Tags: javascript, json, typescript

Boa tarde.

Tenho uma aplicação que faz uma requisição no meu banco de dados e retorna um json. Esse json contem uma lista de objetos, que no meu caso são produtos, estou com dificuldades para resgatar as informações pois quando tento usar um forEach para interar dentro da lista e devolver os objeto esta ocorrendo um erro. 
Como eu posso resgatar essas informações?

Sugue em anexo um fragmento do JSON:

```html
{docs: Array(7977), warning: "no matching index found, create an index to optimize query time"}
docs: Array(7977)
[0 … 99]
0: {_id: "produto-1", descricao: "LANTERNA DIANT DIR", referencia: "KADETTE"}
1: {_id: "produto-10", descricao: "HELICE", referencia: "4044/46923"}
2: {_id: "produto-100", descricao: "BOMBA DE OLEO", referencia: "BO0205/10055"}
3: {_id: "produto-1000", descricao: "CABO DO TRATOMETRO", referencia: "229370"}
```

O código que tentei usar para extrair os objeto foi:

```html
this.localdb.find(req).then((result) => {
  if (result === undefined) {
    rej('Erro: Não foi possivel carregar os dados');
  } else {
    result.array.forEach(element => {
    console.log(element);
  });
    res(result);
}
```

O objeto inicial era so imprimir no log, porem apresenta a mensagem: 'Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined'

Comment: `result.array` é nulo. Faça um *debug* ou use `console.log(result)` para identificar o valor da variável.

Comment: Acho que o **array** no forEach deve ser Maiúsculo não?!

Comment: LeAndrade, eu fiz estes testes antes e a sintaxe esta ok. Porém não esta funcionando. A questão está sendo como extrair essas informações. O result esta sendo preenchido, e se eu exibir com o console.log(result) apresenta o json. Minha duvida é como posso extrair essas informações pois a estrutura esta mais ou menos assim: {  docs:  
0: {_id: "produto-1", descricao: "LANTERNA DIANT DIR", referencia: "KADETTE"}
}

Comment: Não está dando para saber exatamente qual é o tipo de retorno da Api, sé é um array de objetos, essa sintaxe **`0: {...} 1: {...}`** não conheço.

Comment: @Gustavomgu.developer sua pergunta tem duas resposta, nós aqui operamos por um sistema de méritos e pontuação. Se alguma das resposta for útil e responde a sua pergunta você poderia aceita-lá. Caso não saiba como fazer para aceitar uma resposta veja o nosso [Tour](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour).

Answer (score 1):

## Análise

Na questão não ficou claro o formato desse seu documento JSON não dá para saber se é realmente um array ou se a ferramenta que você usou para fazer o dump formatou a saída dos dados em um objeto.

Então eu vi três possibilidades para o formato de seu documento:

**1 . Ser um objeto de objetos**

```
{"docs": {
    "0": {"_id": "produto-1", "descricao": "LANTERNA DIANT DIR", "referencia": "KADETTE"},
    "1": {"_id": "produto-10", "descricao": "HELICE", "referencia": "4044/46923"},
    "2": {"_id": "produto-100", "descricao": "BOMBA DE OLEO", "referencia": "BO0205/10055"},
    "3": {"_id": "produto-1000", "descricao": "CABO DO TRATOMETRO", "referencia": "229370"}}
}
```

**2 . Ser um objeto de um array de objetos**

```
{ "docs": [
   {"_id": "produto-1", "descricao": "LANTERNA DIANT DIR", "referencia": "KADETTE"},
   {"_id": "produto-10", "descricao": "HELICE", "referencia": "4044/46923"},
   {"_id": "produto-100", "descricao": "BOMBA DE OLEO", "referencia": "BO0205/10055"},
   {"_id": "produto-1000", "descricao": "CABO DO TRATOMETRO", "referencia": "229370"}]
}
```

**3 . ser simplesmente um array de objetos**

```
[
  {"_id": "produto-1", "descricao": "LANTERNA DIANT DIR", "referencia": "KADETTE"},
  {"_id": "produto-10", "descricao": "HELICE", "referencia": "4044/46923"},
  {"_id": "produto-100", "descricao": "BOMBA DE OLEO", "referencia": "BO0205/10055"},
  {"_id": "produto-1000", "descricao": "CABO DO TRATOMETRO", "referencia": "229370"}
]
```

Como não pude determinar o formato exato do documento pela pergunta decidi criar uma função que analisa os três possíveis formatos e exibe um relatório dos produtos contidos no documento.

## Desenvolvimento

A função chama-se `logElements(doc, root)` e aceita dois strings como parâmetro `doc` é uma string em um dos três formatos descritos acima e root é raiz do documento nos dois primeiros formatos.

Essa função criada para entender o problema é baseada no código da pergunta e foi feita para que possa ser facilmente ser reintegrada ao código original.

Seu funcionamento é extrair um objeto do documento JSON, passado como parâmetro `doc`, usando o método [`JSON.parse(string)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) e verificar se é um array(terceiro caso), se não for array ele converte o objeto para um array usando o método [`Object.values(obj)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values) o objeto identificado por`root` como alvo da conversão em array. A função termina fazendo um relatório usando a sintaxe correta do método [`Array.prototype.forEach(callback(currentValue)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach).

```js
// Objeto de objetos
var jsonCaso1 = `{ "docs": {
"0": {"_id": "produto-1", "descricao": "LANTERNA DIANT DIR", "referencia": "KADETTE"},
"1": {"_id": "produto-10", "descricao": "HELICE", "referencia": "4044/46923"},
"2": {"_id": "produto-100", "descricao": "BOMBA DE OLEO", "referencia": "BO0205/10055"},
"3": {"_id": "produto-1000", "descricao": "CABO DO TRATOMETRO", "referencia": "229370"}
}}`;

// Objeto de uma array objetos 
var jsonCaso2 = `{ "docs": [
 {"_id": "produto-1", "descricao": "LANTERNA DIANT DIR", "referencia": "KADETTE"},
 {"_id": "produto-10", "descricao": "HELICE", "referencia": "4044/46923"},
 {"_id": "produto-100", "descricao": "BOMBA DE OLEO", "referencia": "BO0205/10055"},
 {"_id": "produto-1000", "descricao": "CABO DO TRATOMETRO", "referencia": "229370"}
]}`;

//Array de objetos
var jsonCaso3 = `[
 {"_id": "produto-1", "descricao": "LANTERNA DIANT DIR", "referencia": "KADETTE"},
 {"_id": "produto-10", "descricao": "HELICE", "referencia": "4044/46923"},
 {"_id": "produto-100", "descricao": "BOMBA DE OLEO", "referencia": "BO0205/10055"},
 {"_id": "produto-1000", "descricao": "CABO DO TRATOMETRO", "referencia": "229370"}
]`;


console.log("=".repeat(10) + "Teste JSON caso 1" + "=".repeat(10));
logElements(jsonCaso1 , "docs");

console.log("=".repeat(10) + "Teste JSON caso 2" + "=".repeat(10));
logElements(jsonCaso2 , "docs");

console.log("=".repeat(10) + "Teste JSON caso 3" + "=".repeat(10));
logElements(jsonCaso3);



function logElements(doc, root){
  // Convert JSON para objeto
  var obj = JSON.parse(doc);
  if (obj === undefined){
      console.log('Erro: Não foi possivel carregar os dados');
  } else {
      // Se o objeto convertido não for array converte o objeto cujo o nome ésta armazenado em root em array 
      if (!Array.isArray(obj)) obj = Object.values(obj[root]);

      // Imprime o relatório, note a sintaxe de forEach se o objeto já é um Array é só usar direto.
      obj.forEach(element => {
           console.log("\nProduto = " + element._id + "\nDescrição = " + element.descricao + "\nReferência = " + element.referencia + "\n" + "-".repeat(40));
      });
  }
}
```

## Resposta

Aplicando os conceitos utilizados para criar a função `logElements` ao seu código e supondo que `result` seja uma string no formato JSON obtida provavelmente de um DB NoSQL:

```
this.localdb.find(req).then((result) => {
  // Convert JSON para objeto
  var result = JSON.parse(doc);
  if (result === undefined) {
    rej('Erro: Não foi possivel carregar os dados');
  } else {
      // Se o objeto convertido não for array converte o objeto 
      if (!Array.isArray(result )) result = Object.values(result["docs"]);
         result.forEach(element => {
         console.log(element);
      });
    res(result);
 }
});
```

Comment: Muito Obrigado Augusto Vasques, a sua resposta me ajudou muito aqui. E desculpe por não ter sido o mais claro possível na explicação do meu problema.

Answer (score 0):

hmm... O que você tem aí não é bem um Array, mas dá pra fazer mais ou menos assim:

```
var objetos = {
    docs : {
        0: {_id: "produto-1", descricao: "--", referencia: "--"},
        1: {_id: "produto-2", descricao: "--", referencia: "--"},
        2: {_id: "produto-3", descricao: "--", referencia: "--"},
        3: {_id: "produto-4", descricao: "--", referencia: "--"},
        4: {_id: "produto-5", descricao: "--", referencia: "--"},
        5: {_id: "produto-6", descricao: "--", referencia: "--"},
    }
}

Object.keys(objetos.docs).forEach(function(key, index){
    let doc = objetos.docs[key]
    console.log(key+' = '+doc._id);
})
```

Espero que entenda ao menos um pouco do que eu tentei fazer, não acho que seja exatamente o que você quer, mas chega perto.

Como se trata de um Objeto, eu pego as '**keys**' que nesse caso é como se fossem os índices desses outros objetos dentro de `docs` e a partir dessas **keys** eu pego individualmente cada objeto dentro do forEach e faço o que eu quiser (no caso do exemplo, um simples `console.log()`).